# Wrapping multiple CSS elements under one id

Tags: html, css

I am trying to write CSS that only applies to certain Divs. I have code that works for this example, but I would like to do it in a way that doesn't require me to put `.landing` in front of every line

HTML

```
<div class="landing">
    <h1>Hey</h1>
    <p>Hi</p>
</div>
<div class="notlanding">
    <h1>Hey</h1>
    <p>Hi</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.landing h1{
    color: red;
  }
.landing p {
    color: blue;
  }
```

This produces what I want to accomplish, but is there a way to wrap both `h1` and `p` in `.landing`?

Something like this

```
.landing {
   h1{
      color: red;
    }
  p {
      color: blue;
    }
 }
```

Comment: That would be possible using a CSS preprocessor (LESS, SASS, ...) but not with pure CSS

Comment: you can use ```div:not(.landing)``` for the others, not sure if thats what you wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this way you can not use in `CSS`.

But you can use `SASS` - Syntactically Awesome StyleSheet

> http://sass-lang.com/

`SASS` allows you to write dynamic `css` like variable declaration and much more. Just check above link.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that if we'd be using a css compiler like less or sass... I think you can't do it in pure css.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is using Shadow DOM (not widely supported yet). Then, your landing div cound be a shadow root and could have its own stylesheet... this basically works in Angular 2 today.